# Why does push function inside for loop gets called multiple time in each iteration instead of just once for every iteration?

Tags: c, stack

I wish to reverse a sentence word by word using a stack. 

 

Input: first second third

Expected output: third second first 

Actual output: third third third


I am getting the desired result by using push outside for loop but not inside for loop.


Code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 50
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef struct
{
    int top;
    char* s[MAX];
} stack;

bool isFull(stack *ps)
{
    if(ps->top == MAX - 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void push(stack *ps, char* x)
{
    if(!isFull(ps))
        ps->s[++(ps->top)] = x;
    else
        printf("Error: overflow\n");
}

void display(stack *ps)
{
    int i;
    for(i = ps->top; i > -1; i--)
        printf("%s ", ps->s[i]);
}

int main()
{
    stack sentence;
    stack* ps = &sentence;
    sentence.top = -1;
    int n, i;
    char word[20];
    printf("No. of words: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", word);
        push(ps, word);
    }
    display(ps);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: you have to store your *word*, here you put all your word into your `char word[20]` you need to allocate memory for each word

Comment: You are pushing the same buffer.

Comment: Your stack stores the addresses of the stings, it should store the strings itself.

Comment: Try `char word[20];` --> `char word[MAX][20];`, `scanf("%s", word);
        push(ps, word);` --> `scanf("%19s", word[i]);
  push(ps, word[i]);`

Comment: ..someting that would be obvious from your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack data type is defined as -

```
typedef struct
{
    int top;
    char* s[MAX];
} stack;
```

char* s[MAX] - It is array of pointer. You are not assigning memory here and just creating a pointer array which can hold address of character in each element.
And in push function you are just assigning value to this pointer as address of word. After last execution of for loop,value of word is "third". Now you are printing value at the address pointed by s[0],s[1],s[2]. These are all currently pointing to word.

1. Either create stack with array of string
   OR
2. Store the word in different variables.

Here point 1 makes sense as we are implementing stack which will hold data values.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise explanation about why the error was occurring. Helped me in understanding a new concept.